# JQuery if both conditions are true perform action

Tags: jquery, scroll, conditional-statements

I have the following code which executes on mobile screens, but the problem is it also executes on large screens.
Can this be change to execute only if both conditions are true?

Thanks

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        var ww = $(window).width();
        var sc = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (ww < 769 && sc > 100){
            $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
            $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 65);
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
            $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 115);
        }

    });
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you believe the issue is with that if conditional.  That conditional is going to result in true/false dependent upon the values the variables hold.  They must both be true for the if {} block to happen.  Are you saying if the ww is > a certain value, you don't want the else to happen?

Comment: Yes, just to quickly explain, this code works well on mobile screens another words if statement happens, however on larger screens last part of the else statement still remains and adds 115 to position.

Comment: I changed it to this, and it seems to be working, not sure if its correct.

if($(window).width() < 769){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var ww = $(window).width();
                var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (ww < 769 && sc > 100){
                    $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
                    $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 65);
                } else {
                    $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
                    $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 115);
                }
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

So from your comment you need to provide a conditional for the else block, or the whole block, to prevent it from running.

```
    if (ww < 769 && sc > 100){
        $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 65);
    } else if (ww < 2048) { //or whatever your value for a 'large' screen starts at
        $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 115);
    }
```

or

```
    if (www < 2048) {
      if (ww < 769 && sc > 100){
          $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
          $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 65);
      } else {
          $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
          $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 115);
      }
    }
```

The first would prevent the else from happening for large screens.  The second would prevent the whole if else from happening for large screens.

Comment: I have not tried these solutions, but, I will definitely test these later as I really want to see which approach is better. for now I will post my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(window).width() < 769){
        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var ww = $(window).width();
            var sc = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (ww < 769 && sc > 100){
                $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
                $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 65);
            } else {
                $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
                $('.page-sidebar').css('top', 115);
            }

        });
    }
```